# How can I stop the page from breaking mid td?

Tags: html, css, printing

```
  <table class="question-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="question-text">1.
          <p>$153$ + $634$ = ___</p>
        </div>
        <ol type="A">
          <li>$787$</li>
          <li>$456$</li>
          <li>$657$</li>
          <li>$936$</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td class="answer"><small>answer</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="question-text">2.
          <p>$38$ + $47$ = __</p>
        </div>
        <ol type="A">
          <li>$106$</li>
          <li>$85$</li>
          <li>$96$</li>
          <li>$52$</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td class="answer"><small>answer</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="question-text">3.
          <p>$32$ + $25$ = __</p>
        </div>
        <ol type="A">
          <li>$76$</li>
          <li>$58$</li>
          <li>$57$</li>
          <li>$24$</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td class="answer"><small>answer</small></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS is

```
.question-table {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.question-table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But when I print, it still breaks in the middle of the `TR / TD`:
[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you try setting td, div, ol, li { page-break-after: avoid; } combined with tr { page-break-before: always; } ?

Comment: No dice - didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a thought, but have you possibly tried adding Css to the `<td>` tag? maybe by giving it a certain width?

```
    <style>
       td {
       width:300px;
}
       </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.question-table tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

update: together with

```
.question-table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Tried that - no dice

Comment: @Shamoon It worked for me. Did you have `avoid` for both the td and the tr?